# How to replace excel negative number with a zero?

Tags: excel

I have the following formula and sometimes the output is a negative number, how would you replace the negative output with a zero as part of the same formula? Negative is produced from (60-A1)*2*J1. Thanks!

```
=IF((60-A1)*2*J1>$A$2,$A$2,(60-A10)*2*K1)
```

Comment: wrap the whole thing into another IF and output a 0 if negative

Comment: @GowthamShiva: The problem with that approach is that you end up having to type the formula twice.

Comment: You could just use A1 to check if it is more than 60

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use MAX():

```
=MAX(IF((60-A1)*2*J1>$A$2,$A$2,(60-A10)*2*K1),0)
```

Answer (score 2):

A crude way, which does work surprisingly well for simple data of reasonable magnitude is to wrap your formula with

```
=IFERROR(EXP(LN(<your formula here>)),0)
```

This has the nice property that you don't need to repeat your formula.

It works since `LN` will fail on a non-positive number, and `EXP` reverses out the `LN`.

(A technical note: Excel uses an IEEE754 floating point double type for its numerical values, and `LN` and `EXP` are fairly natural functions to apply to binary floating point types.)

Comment: Thanks Bathsheba.

Comment: @John: Pleasure, and you were wise to accept the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, the function that leaves positive numbers alone but replaces negative numbers by zero is called the [positive part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts) function. If you use it a lot, you could define it as a VBA function and use it directly in the worksheet. In a standard code module, enter:

```
Function PositivePart(x As Double) As Double
    PositivePart = IIf(x >= 0, x, 0)
End Function
```

And then in the worksheet use:

```
=PositivePart(IF((60-A1)*2*J1>$A$2,$A$2,(60-A10)*2*K1))
```